# Django-CMS `render_model` templatetag issue

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm attempting to take advantage of the [`render_model`](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/frontend_models.html#editing-ordinary-django-models) templatetag in a template for a custom plugin in [Django-CMS](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/index.html). I've followed the documentation and other plugin examples, but I'm still encountering an error when adding the plugin to a page. The stack trace I'm shown ends in [`pluginmodel.py`](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/models/pluginmodel.py):

```
File "/vendor/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/pluginmodel.py" in get_breadcrumb
  406.    breadcrumb.append({'title': force_text(self.get_plugin_name()), 'url': url})

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

Calling `get_plugin_name` on `self` (which is an instance of my model) seems to be raising the error. What could be causing this? Any insight would be appreciated.

For Reference, I'm using Python 2.7, Django 1.7, and Django-CMS 3.1.3. Here's a stripped-down version what I've defined so far:

**models.py**

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class PageBlock(CMSPlugin):
    content = HTMLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return Truncator(strip_tags(self.content)).words(3, truncate="...")
```

**cms_plugins.py**

```
class PageBlockPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = models.PageBlock
    name = _("Page Block")
    render_template = "some_template.html"

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context["instance"] = instance
        return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(PageBlockPlugin)
```

**admin.py**

```
class PageBlockAdmin(FrontendEditableAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(models.PageBlock, PageBlockAdmin)
```

**some_template.html**

```
{% load cms_tags %}
{% render_model instance "content" %}
```

`{{instance.content | safe}}` seems to work just fine, but every example I've looked at uses the `render_model` approach instead.

Comment: I've been able to reproduce this but not quite had time to pin down exactly which of my plugin's triggered it. Hopefully I'll get time to have another look soon.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look!